# Excluding remote branches from "git log -all"

Tags: git

Are there ways to list the git log graph from all local branches only?

Consider the command:
`git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all`

Where the "**--all**" flag would be something like "**--localbranchesonly**".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`--all` means "everything in `refs/`" (plus HEAD as well).

`--branches` means "everything in `refs/heads/`".

`--remotes` means "everything in "`refs/remotes/`".

`--tags` means "everything in "`refs/tags/`".

Except for `--all`, they all take optional patterns that restrict the match even further.

As [Josh Lee mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42836803/1256452), `--exclude` can be used to limit the matches.  There is also `--glob`, which is like `--all` in that it applies to all references, but like the others in that it accepts a pattern.  Hence `--branches=<pattern>` essentially means `--glob=refs/heads/<pattern>`.  Note that these are shell style globs, not regular expressions; and metacharacters in them may need to be protected from the shell.

Answer (score 3):

`git log --branches` will show everything under `refs/heads`, which should limit you to all local branches. [Doc for --branches](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---branchesltpatterngt).

You could also do `git log --exclude=refs/remotes/* --all`, which is more complicated but will give you exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! This is much clearer! Thank you